# show values of two columns from two different tables into one column in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

there are two tables 1) participant and 2) logindatetime.
for first time login datetime value along with other user data like,Name, location, contact number, email gets inserted into participant table having datatime column...for any subsequent login of the same user we insert datetime value into logindatetime column to keep the records of how many times the user logged in....now i have to show all the login time (first login time and subsequent login time) in a single column along with name, location, contact I number, email of the same user.
(I do have an identity in participant table).

Have tried following query:

```
select a.firstname as 'Name', a.Email as 'Email', a.Address1 as 'Location', 
    a.MobileNo as 'Contact', COALESCE(a.datetime, b.datetime) as DateTime 
from eventonline.participant a, eventonline.logindatetime b 
where a.Id = b.Rid";
```

but it show first login time multiple times.

Comment: I have tired following query :-
a.firstname as 'Name', a.Email as 'Email', a.Address1 as 'Location', a.MobileNo as 'Contact', COALESCE(a.datetime, b.datetime) as DateTime from eventonline.participant a, eventonline.logindatetime b where a.Id = b.Rid";
but it show first login time multiple times.

Comment: You need to post a LOT more information if you want any real help. This is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ Also, based on your comment you should also read this article. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this to fetch the first and then the other logons separately:

```
select a.firstname as Name, a.Email, a.Address1 as Location, 
    a.MobileNo as Contact, a.datetime 
from eventonline.participant a

union all

select a.firstname as Name, a.Email, a.Address1 as Location, 
    a.MobileNo as Contact, b.datetime 
from eventonline.participant a
join eventonline.logindatetime b on a.Id = b.Rid
```

It might be easier just to add the first logon to logindatetime

Comment: Can't add first logon to logindatetime...but Thank you a lot...your solution worked... :)

Comment: Just added one extra data to this query and found the exact result.

select a.firstname as Name, a.Email as Email, a.Address1 as Location, a.MobileNo as Contact, a.datetime, a.ID from eventonline.participant a where a.eventid = '130516'union all select a.firstname as Name, a.Email as Email, a.Address1 as Location, a.MobileNo as Contact, b.datetime, b.Rid from eventonline.participant a join eventonline.logindatetime b on a.Id = b.Rid where b.eventid = '130516'  order by datetime desc

Comment: but now i m stuck in other situation....where I have to get only last login date in the grid along with name, mobileno, contact, lastlogintime....i have tried 'top 1' but only getting one result....can some one advice??

Comment: @dhaval you need to do a cross apply to logindatetime and the top 1 should be inside the cross apply

Answer (score 0):

JamesZ's answer gives the solution but a further note on why your approach isn't working. You're joining the two tables and using `coalesce(a.DateTime, b.DateTime)` to display login time. If the user has logged in before, `a.DateTime` has a non-null value. `coalesce(x,y)` only uses `y` if `x` is null. But that's not the real problem. The first login-time needs a record of its own in the logindatetime table. If the users logs in 5 times, your logindatetime will have 4 rows and that's all you'll see when joining the two tables. You need to either save the first login time as a row in logindatetime, or use a UNION to force that first login time to be added as an extra row.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue but according to [James Z's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37146469/4424636) I solved my problem:

```
select a.start_date as start, a.end_date as end, a.rooms_id as roomid from maintenance a UNION ALL SELECT b.check_in as start, b.check_out as end, b.room_id AS roomid from reservations b
```

The result of the query from both tables are here:

[image: The result of the query from both tables are here]

Answer (score -1):

You could use joins in your sql statement, i just learnt them 3 days ago and they are very useful!

it would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column1 = table2.column1 
WHERE table1.column1 = '$yourVar';
```

table1.column1 could be the id, and the corresponding id in the second table can be the id that links it to the first table (Foreign key), it will retrieve the data of the first table and bring all the data of the second table as well that would match the on the  `ON` criteria

Comment: if you down vote please explain why... it seems the answer is valid and i have used it for a problem similar to this.